# Sequelize workFlow is not associated to user

Tags: node.js, associations, sequelize.js, has-many, belongs-to

I am working on  **"sequelize": "^4.32.2"** & facing issue when I use belongTO association. Below is my code

This is my main file in which I create associations between tables.

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = require('./../database')(Sequelize);
var Users = sequelize.import('./usersSchema');
var WorkFlows = sequelize.import('./workFlowsSchema');

//Create user association with workFLow
Users.hasMany(WorkFlows);
//Create workFlow association with user
WorkFlows.belongsTo(Users);
```

usersSchema.Js file code given below

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
//create table schema
var Users = sequelize.define('user', {
    id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
}, {
    timestamps: true, // timestamps will now be true,
});
//bydefault force is false if it's true then it delete table & create it again

Users.sync({
    force: false
});
return Users;
```

}

workFlowsSchema.js file contains code

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
//create table schema
var WorkFlows = sequelize.define('workFlow', {
    assign_to: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    assign_by: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    status_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    hash_id: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    pair_code: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER
    },
    archived: {
        type: DataTypes.BOOLEAN,
        defaultValue: false,
    },
    start_time: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
    end_time: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
    },
}, {
    timestamps: true, // timestamps will now be true
});


WorkFlows.sync({
    force: false // timestamps will now be true
});

return WorkFlows;
```

}

When execute

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = require('./../database')(Sequelize);
var Users = sequelize.import('./usersSchema');
var workFlows = sequelize.import('./workFlowsSchema');
const Op = Sequelize.Op;

Users.count({
    where: conditions,
    include: [{
        all:false,
        model: workFlows
       }]
}).then(function(count) {
    return count;
}).catch(function(err) {
    return err;
});
```

I am getting bellow Error

**{ SequelizeEagerLoadingError: workFlow is not associated to user!
    at Function._getIncludedAssociation (\node_modules\sequelize\lib\model.js:582:13)**

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you're not defining the associations in the model files instead of main ?

Comment: Actually I divided my code in MVC architecture. You are right when I execute query in same file where I defined associations It's working fine.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working! If possible, would you gladly kindly accept my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the provided code it is likely that the associations aren't being synchronized properly before execution. In general, as shown in the Sequelize documentation, it's best practice to associate the models in the files whereby they are defined.

In a case where that is not possible, ensure the changes are synchronized with the database.